# Adhoc Provisioning profile generated from provisioning portal showing expiry date of June 25, 2079

Tags: iphone, provisioning-profile

I generated an ad-hoc profile which shows up the expiry date of June 25, 2079. Is this correct or a bug in the provisioning portal?

[image: Image showing error snapshot]

Thanks

Comment: It's definitely not supposed to last so long.

Comment: May this be connected with the updates for iCloud?

Comment: Have no idea but haven't heard anyone else complaining about this issue.

Comment: The AdHoc profile I generated today says the same thing - 2029.  None of my past AdHoc profiles lasted beyond a year.  The question is -- does it work?

Comment: It isn't working for me with xcode 4.2.

Comment: I had a client create a new App Store profile today and it expires 2079 as well. This profile worked fine for submitting an app.

Comment: Thanks. It is working for me with xcode 4.0.2 now.

Comment: Hah, that happened to me as well. Probably a bug, but who cares, you won't have to update your provisioning profile anytime soon! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that sometime this week Apple changed the rules on expiration for new distribution certificates. Instead of expiring when your program period runs out they are expiring in 2079. I've been able to successfully submit an app using the new certificate so at least right now this seems to be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was a bug because Apple has revoked all the provisioning profiles we created in the last week that had this 2070 issue.

Answer (score 0):

2079 here for me too! Glad others are seeing no errors with it.  I have been using the new Provision for Ad Hoc without fault.  Googling 2079 and Provision brings us to this page.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a provisioning profile with the 2079 expiration date. Apple let me submit one version of the app with this profile but as of today it says it is an invalid signature so I guess they changed the policy (without telling anyone).